# gulp.series doesn't serialize task

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, gulp-4

I'm using gulp 4 with Node 8 and the following setting

```js
gulp.task('task1', function(done) {
  gulp.src(...)
      .pipe(debug({title: 'TASK1'})
      .pipe(...)
  done();
});

gulp.task('task2', function(done) {
  gulp.src(...)
      .pipe(debug({title: 'TASK2'})
      .pipe(...)
  done();
});

gulp.task('task3', function(done) {
  gulp.src(...)
      .pipe(debug({title: 'TASK3'})
      .pipe(...)
  done();
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.series(gulp.parallel('task1', 'task2'), 'task3'));
```

This is what I see when the task runs--they all run parallely

`[23:41:57] TASK1 src/
[23:41:57] TASK1 src/
[23:41:57] TASK1 src/
[23:41:57] TASK1 src/
[23:41:58] TASK3 src/
[23:41:59] TASK2 src/
[23:41:59] TASK2 src/
[23:41:59] TASK2 src/
[23:41:59] TASK1 src/
[23:41:59] TASK1 src/
[23:41:59] TASK3 src/
[23:41:59] TASK3 src/
[23:41:59] TASK1 src/
[23:41:59] TASK1 src/
[23:41:59] TASK1 src/
[23:42:00] TASK1 src/
[23:42:00] TASK3 src/
[23:42:00] TASK2 src/
[23:42:00] TASK2 src/
[23:42:00] TASK2 src/
[23:42:00] TASK2 src/
[23:42:00] TASK3 src/
[23:42:00] TASK3 src/
[23:42:00] TASK3 src/
[23:42:00] TASK1 src/`

Anyone experienced the same issue? Is there a fix for this?

Thanks,

Comment: reread the docs ... https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/running-tasks-in-series.md

Comment: yeah, I was mixing some 3.9 and 4.0 old style. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I didn't signal async completion properly. With gulp 4, I don't need to use callback in the task function. Instead I should just use `return`.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but returning doesn't solve it.